# How to convert a PDF to a PDF/A?

Tags: pdf, conversion

My university requires submitted PDF files to be in [PDF/A format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A).

I tried to find a converter, but they are all very expensive and/or complicated.

How do I convert my existing PDF file into a PDF/A?

Comment: If it's only word-processing documents with simple formatting, you could open them in OpenOffice and save them as PDF (OpenOffice has a native PDF export but I don't know if it's PDF/A compliant). Other than that, ask your school if they can provide any tools, seeing as it's *their* requirement to do this.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) lets you export text documents as PDF/A, as explained [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Export_as_PDF#Archive_PDF.2FA-1a_.28ISO_19005-1.29).

Comment: @ThatGuy -100 read the question: he was asking to convert PDF!!!

Comment: @Tomas: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ ...I wasn't answering OP's question. I was clearly responding to FrustratedWithFormsDesigner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For saving existing Word documents to PDF/A all you need is a recent version of Microsoft Word. For creating from other products that print you can use a free PDF/A creator like the one at [www.freepdfcreator.org](http://www.freepdfcreator.org)

If you need to validate that a PDF/A file is compliant, you can use our free service at [www.validatepdfa.com](http://www.validatepdfa.com)

Converting existing PDF files to PDF/A in a lossless way is a bit more tricky and not always possible. Acrobat 9 and 10 can do this. 
Our business, Solid Documents, also sells a product that does this (and other common archiving functions) for $99:
[Solid PDF Tools](http://www.soliddocuments.com/products.htm?product=SolidPDFTools)

Comment: Unfortunately Free PDF Creator often caused the programs I tried to print from to hang or crash, and briefly flashed some popup about "special offers."  When I contacted Solid Documents support, I was advised that "Free version is an intermediate release, and we cannot consider its issues."

Comment: Kurt Pfeifle's answer below is way better.

Answer (score 19):

PDF**/A** is an international ISO standard for **a**rchiving PDFs. The standard requests strict compliance to its set of rules (like: "embed all fonts", "don't use transparencies", "don't use JavaScript", "no encryption",...).

There are a lot of PDFs out there which **claim** to be PDF/A, but fail a real smoke test. That claim is just a tag in the file's metadata. That tag can make f.e. Acrobat Reader display a special hint when rendering it.

A check for real compliancy requires some rather expansive commercial "preflight" software. Currently I'm not aware of any Free utility to do that job. See also here for some test results: [**Isartor testsuite**](https://www.pdfa.org/resource/isartor-test-suite/).

You can use Ghostscript to (try to) convert PDF ***to*** PDF/A. How to do this is [**documented here**](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/trunk/gs/doc/Ps2pdf.htm#PDFA) (***Update:*** **[for newer versions here](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/VectorDevices.htm;hb=HEAD#PDFA)**).

But note: this document was updated only very recently [*****]. Previous versions of Ghostscript's *Ps2pdf.htm* did mis-lead users to run a command that created PDFs *claiming* to be PDF/A but which failed real smoke tests.

#### How to convert PDF to PDF/A with Ghostscript:

Here is a commandline:

```
gswin32c ^
   -dPDFA ^
   -dNOOUTERSAVE ^
   -dUseCIEColor ^
   -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK ^
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
   -o output_pdfa.pdf ^
   -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 ^
    PDFA_def.ps ^
    input.pdf
```

[*****] **Note:** The problem lays with the parameter `PDFA_def.ps`. This is a file you ***need to edit*** to suite your needs. Ghostscript ships with a sample of it in its `/lib` subdirectory. This **sample will not work** as-is without you editing it. How to edit is inside the sample's comments.

Comment: So is it safe to say that PDF/A isn't a file format per se, but really just a set of compliance requirements for creating a PDF file using existing technology?

Comment: @JohnFx: in a way, yes. Every PDF/A-1b (or PDF/A-1a) is also a valid PDF in the general sense. But not every PDF successfully validates as a PDF/A*. The PDF/A-* specifications do 2 things: (1) limit the set of features specified in the general PDF-1.4 specification to a subset of allowed ones;  (2) require to strictly follow a few rules which in the general PDF spec are *"do or don't do -- as you like"* (like embedding all fonts used).

Answer (score 12):

I used the following command to convert PDF to PDF-A:

```
gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE -dUseCIEColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile=MyOutPutPDF-A.pdf PDFOriginal.ps
```

If you have a PDF file, first convert it to PS to work with the above code. I tried several times with the PDF file to be directly converted to PDF-A. However, it didn't work.

Here is a way to convert your PDF to PS file:

```
pdftops PDFOriginal.pdf PDFOriginal.ps
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, these PDFs are not accepted by my university :/

Comment: This was accepted by the US National Science Foundation's system for publication archiving. Thanks!

Comment: The conversion to PS breaks links inside the PDF for me. However, this step is actually unnecessary. `gs` accepts `PDFOriginal.pdf` as input directly, in which case the links are preserved.

Comment: Validation by the university library SLUB Dresden failed :(

Comment: Worked for me and validation was successful!

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Office 2007's '[Save as PDF](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=F1FC413C-6D89-4F15-991B-63B07BA5F2E5&displaylang=en)' tool saves in PDF/A format.

A PDF/A document is just a PDF document that uses a specific subset of PDF that is designed to ensure it is 'self-contained'. Ie it is not permitted to be reliant on information from external sources (e.g. font programs and hyperlinks).
From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A):

> Other key elements to PDF/A
>   compatibility include:
>
> ```
> * Audio and video content are forbidden.
> * JavaScript and executable file launches are forbidden.
> * All fonts must be embedded and also must be legally embeddable for
>   unlimited, universal rendering. This also applies to the so-called     
>   PostScript standard fonts such as Times or Helvetica.
> * Colorspaces specified in a device-independent manner.
> * Encryption is disallowed.
> * Use of standards-based metadata is mandated.
> ```

Edit:

Since there aren't really any tools to test if a PDF is PDF/A, it's a safe bet that just like you, *your university also has no way to test that the document you send them is PDF/A*.

It's likely that the only reason they specifically request it is so they can be sure that all the content will be "there" when they open it. They just expressed this requirement rather cryptically (And badly) as being that it had to be PDF/A. So a simple way to test if the PDF meet their **true** requirement of self-containment is to transfer the PDF and view it from another (preferably offline) computer and ensure that everything appears as it should.

Comment: ah, is there a way to determine if an existing PDF is PDF or PDF/A?

Comment: @ben: I don't know of any tools that determine if a PDF *really* is PDF/A. PDF/A is an international ISO standard for *a*rchiving PDFs. The standard requests **strict** compliance to its set set of rules ("embed all fonts", "don't use transparencies"). There are a lot of PDFs out there which **claim** to be PDF/A, but fail real smoke tests. That claim is just a tag in the file's metadata. That tag can make f.e. Acrobat Reader display a special hint. A check for real compliancy requires some rather expansive commercial software. I'm not aware of any Free utility to do that job.

Comment: Thanks for the info Pipitas - it then seems likely that even the uni are unable to check for certain the the doc is PDF/A, and so it's not a hard requirement - see my edit.

Comment: @imoatama: did you see my other answer? It explains how to convert PDF to PDF/A. If you use `-dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=0`, your PDF will claim to be PDF/A even if Ghostscript's conversion process noticed things that don't comply and which it could not repair. You may have created such type of 'fake' PDF/As as I mentioned elsewhere...

Comment: The MS Word 'save as PDF' also claims the PDF is PDF/A. No need to use Ghostscript.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle To check if a pdf is pdf/a compliant (and to which flavor) one can use the foss tool veraPDF (http://verapdf.org/).

Answer (score 2):

In macOSX without using `pdftops` which I wasn't able to install (as @soham.m17 proposed) you can do:

```
pdf2ps oldPdf.pdf psVersionOfOldps.ps
```

to convert your pdf to ps format and then:

```
gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE -dUseCIEColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile=MyOutPutPDF-A.pdf psVersionOfOldps.ps
```

to convert in pdf/A.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that worked for me on Windows 10 was a slight modification of soham's answer (which for me was working but with errors):

- converting the `PDF` to `ps` (with `pdf2ps source.pdf temp.ps`)
- converting back the `ps` to `PDF/A` using Ghostscript 9.22 with

`gswin64c -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dNOOUTERSAVE -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile=destination.pdf temp.ps`

(You might need to add before `gswin64c` the complete path, which for me was `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.22\bin\` -- the same for `pdf2ps`, in this case the path for me was `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.22\lib\`)

If the resulting file is too big you can omit the `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` option. Without this option the resulting file is smaller (even smaller than the original in my case), but degradation in image quality can be noted.

The resulting `PDF` seems to be conform to `PDF/A` even without the `-dNOOUTERSAVE` option, although less fonts are embedded (maybe someone can explain the difference).

When I say "conforms to `PDF/A`" I mean not only that the `PDF/A` "banner" shows up on Acrobat Reader but that the file passes the online validation provided by https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx

I don't know how much such online validation service is reliable, however it managed to detect non-conforming files that were showing the `PDF/A` "banner" on Acrobat Reader (which therefore does not seem reliable in this respect).

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer:**

You can install [Libre Office](https://www.libreoffice.org) , it's free

Open the PDF and **save as PDF...** [check the PDF/A option]

...you're done!

Answer (score 1):

Use an online converter, for example:
https://pdf.online/pdf-to-pdfa